# Why ".my.cnf" file is empty?

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

I want to edit some of InnoDB variables ,I go to the `.my.cnf` which is located in `home/.my.cnf` I found the file just empty.

And when I check SHOW VARIABLES in MySQL it gives me all the variables and their values.

Why the file is empty and how can I edit the needed variables ? and can that affect my database or damage it in anyway?

NEEDED Variable:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
```

Comment: Perhaps mysql is using configurations not mentioned in home/.my.cnf; but something else.

Comment: Why can't you just add those variables to my.cnf? I did that...

Comment: ok so If I add those variables to the file there is no problem?
and I can add them as they are or i should add a [mysqld] before them?

Comment: If I add them should I restart mysql ?

Comment: yes, you should restart mysql service

Comment: It'll be using `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: As already stated, most probably your server is reading a different configuration file. Check the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `~/.my.cnf` file is usually used for client options (for example changing the default port or host).

`mysqld` will likely start as a different user and **will not** read your `.my.cnf` file.  It is recommended to set these options in `/etc/my.cnf` instead.